# magento 2 add unique key on multiple columns using installschema

Tags: php, database, magento2.2

Here i am trying to create unique key using `installSchema` . Array of
column names is defined here on which columns combinedly i want to
apply unique key

```
$arrayOfColumnsName = array('column1', 'column2');
```

here defined the addIndex method for creating the unique key

```
->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('table_name'),
                $arrayOfColumnsName,
               \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
            $arrayOfColumnsName,
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        )
```

This creates unique key for only first column instead of both columns, needs help for the same

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

```
->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('table_name'),
                ['column1','column2'],
               \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
           ['column1','column2'],
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of your **`$arrayOfColumnsName`** data like this:

```
$arrayOfColumnsName = ['column1', 'column2']
```